# Removed windows 10 compleetly but still seeing blue screen on startup

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, bootable-media

I have installed Ubuntu18 from USB on my HP Probook where it was Windows 10 installed on it. I choose the option Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu while installing. Now on startup, I am still seeing the blue screen of death. Any tips on how I can get out of this and boot into Ubuntu? I have tried pressing F8 and F9, but the same screens loads again and again
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14KO_YnZAICr24qE9EyouQIOLkkocs2SF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This would indicate Ubuntu was not installed on the hard drive, and there's no Linux bootloader.

Comment: Are you sure that Erase Disk formatted the entire HDD? Or possibly just one partition?

Comment: How to erase complete HDD?